# XElement.Load(stream) throws System.NotSupportedException

Tags: windows-phone-7, wp7test

when i am gettting the bytes data,and i am trying to convert into XELement like below

```
using (Stream streamResult = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    XElement xElement = XElement.Load(streamResult); // exception thrown here
}
```

Here's the exception details:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll PageRequest::PostProcess :
>   System.NotSupportedException: NotSupportedException    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos,
>   Int32& outOrChars)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value()    at
>   System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)    at
>   System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
>   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.ReadElementFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions
>   o)    at System.Xml.Linq.XElement..ctor(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
>   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions
>   options)    at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(Stream stream,
>   LoadOptions options)

Is the problem with the XML?

Comment: The reason is contained within the exception details.  Without having the Message property's content along with any InnerException this can't really be answered (unless you have had the exact same problem).

Comment: And that's about as much as I can help you.  Looks like all the APIs are correct.  Might be something in the xml.

Comment: Ya,XML was containing Characters,that was causing issue

Comment: You can add a short answer which shows a snippet of what was causing the error, and after the required waiting period you can select that as correct.  This will close out this question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the System.NotSupportedException in my Windows Phone app when the stream didn't contain valid XML.

In my case I was using the response stream from a web request that was returning an error page in some cases.